# Wordpress routing

Tags: wordpress, маршрутизация, wp-plugin

Добрый день.Пишу плагин для вордпресс,  хочу  при нажатии кнопки добавить свой урл. Например,

> localhost -> localhost/title/text.

пользовалась  add_rewrite_rule() , но не  работает. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Без конкретики помочь не получится. Что во что вы хотите переписать? С какой целью? Где ваш код?